# assignment in 2D array - Python

Tags: python, arrays, arraylist, variable-assignment

I am new in Python.
I am trying to assignment a variables in 2D array, I am using For-loop just for the first dimensional, the second dimensional i am assignmenting by myself:

```
A = [3, 4]
B = []

for i in range(len(A)):
B[i*2][0] = 5
B[i*2][1] = 6
B[i*2][2] = 7

B[i*2 +1][0] = 10
B[i*2 +1][1] = 10
B[i*2 +1][2] = 10
```

I am expecting to see matrix B[4][3]:

B[0] = [5, 6, 7]

B[1] = [10, 10, 10]

B[2] = [5, 6, 7]

B[3] = [10, 10, 10]

but i am receiving this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\Python\assignment1_materials\ex1_student_solution.py", line 30, in <module>
B[i*2][0] = 5
IndexError: list index out of range
```

what I am making wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the array `B` is initialized as an empty 1-dimensional array. In order to initialize this to a 4x3 array, we need to do something like so:

```
B = [[0 for i in range(3)] for j in range(4)]
```

If we don't do so, then the code such as `B[2][2]` wouldn't work because there is no memory allocated to those indexes.

Thus the overall code would look something like so:

```
A = [3, 4]
B = [[0 for i in range(3)] for j in range(4)]

for i in range(len(A)):
  B[i*2][0] = 5
  B[i*2][1] = 6
  B[i*2][2] = 7

  B[i*2 +1][0] = 10
  B[i*2 +1][1] = 10
  B[i*2 +1][2] = 10
```

Comment: @KellyBundy sorry for that, I have fixed the minute error now. What I had done before was declare `B=[[0]*3]*4`. However, that was incorrect because Python creates a shallow list for each row which caused improper assignment of values. Read more about shallow lists here:(https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html).

Comment: @ShitijGovil `[0] * 3` is fine and usual, btw, just the outer repetition was problematic.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that B is an empty list. At the line for example,

```
B[i*2][0] = 5
```

You are trying to assign something to `B[0][0]` which does not exist, since B is currently [] (empty). There could be couple of ways to remedy this.

1. Make sure the indices are there for assignment later on. That is, the index B[0][0] exists before hand, and then you can choose to assign that. You can do this by initializing it as :

   `B = [[None]*4 for x in range(2*len(A))]`

B will look like

```
[[None, None, None, None],
 [None, None, None, None],
 [None, None, None, None],
 [None, None, None, None]]
```

Then you can assign values to its indices.

2. The other way is to do it in a lazy way. That is when you want to assign a value, then keep appending to B. (.append() will create a new index and assign your value to it).

It will look something like :

```
for i in range(len(A)) : 
    tmp = []
    tmp.append(5)
    tmp.append(6)
    tmp.append(7)
    B.append(tmp)

    tmp = []
    tmp.append(10)
    tmp.append(10)
    tmp.append(10)
    B.append(tmp)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!